# Relationship between convex functions and coercivity

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, coercive

I was struggling with this problem:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable convex function. Show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ the function $g_\epsilon (x) = f(x) + \epsilon \|x\|^2$ is coercive.

I'm a little confused as to the relationship between a continuously differentiable convex function and coercivity. I know the definitions of a convex function and a coercive function, but I'm unsure if they're related in some way that would help me prove this. Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x) \geq f(z)+\langle \nabla f (z),x-z\rangle$ for a **fixed** $z$. Now estimate below using Cauchy-Schwarz as follows:
\begin{align*}
\epsilon\|x\|^2 + f(x) &\geq \epsilon\|x\|^2+ f(z)+\langle \nabla f (z),x-z\rangle\\
&\geq \epsilon \|x\|^2 +f(z) - \|\nabla f(z)\|\cdot\|x-z\|\\
&\geq \epsilon \|x\|^2 +f(z) - \|\nabla f(z)\|\cdot \left(\|x\|-\|z\|\right)\\
&\to \infty \quad \text{as $\|x\|\to\infty$.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. I know that since $f$ is continuously differentiable and convex, that $f(y) \ge f(x)+ \nabla f(x)^T (y - x) \: \forall x, y \in$ the convex set $C$ which $f$ is in. This looks similar to what you wrote, but I'm still unsure of how this fits into proving coercivity. I'm trying to prove that both $f(x)$ and $\epsilon ||x||^2$ go to infinity as $||x||$ goes to infinity, thus making this function coercive. Is this the right path or am I off? Thanks

Comment: You are right, I forgot the gradient. Let me fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a little unsure of the first couple lines though. How did you get $\epsilon ||x||^2 + f(x) \ge \epsilon ||x||^2 f(z) + \langle \nabla f(z), x-z  \rangle $?

Comment: Typos fixed, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I think it makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R^n$ then
\begin{align}
\langle x_1 - x_2, \nabla g_\epsilon(x_1) - \nabla g_\epsilon(x_2) \rangle &= 
\langle x_1 - x_2, \nabla f(x_1) + 2 \epsilon x_1 - (\nabla f(x_2) + 2 \epsilon x_2) \rangle \\
&= \underbrace{\langle x_1 - x_2, \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2) \rangle}_{\geq 0}
+ 2 \epsilon \underbrace{\langle x_1 - x_2, x_1 - x_2 \rangle}_{\|x_1 - x_2 \|_2^2} \\
&\geq 2 \epsilon \|x_1 - x_2 \|_2^2.
\end{align}
This shows that $g_\epsilon$ is coercive.

(The inequality
$$
\langle x_1 - x_2, \nabla f(x_1) - \nabla f(x_2) \rangle \geq 0
$$
expresses the fact that $\nabla f$ is monotone.)